# Sum of probability is sum of expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I'm having some trouble understanding the following claim from Durrett's probability theory and examples.

It's given that
$X_n$ independent with $E[X_n] = 0$ for $p(n)$ > 1, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_{n}\right|^{p(n)}\right]<\infty$

Part of the solution invokes the following claim

For any $p(n) \in(0,2]$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left[\left|X_{n}\right|>1\right] \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_{n}\right|^{p(n)} \mathbb{I}_{\left\{\left|X_{n}\right|>1\right\}}\right] \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_{n}\right|^{p(n)}\right]<\infty
$$

I understand the second inequality, but the first I'm a little lost.

Thanks

Comment: What is $p(n)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|X(n)|^{p(n)}I_{|x_n| >1} \geq I_{|X_n| >1}$ Take expecatation on both sides.

Comment: Overlooked that, thank you!